# tensorflow "your input ran out of data" error despite generator being an infinite loop

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to follow François Chollet's code from [*Deep Learning with R*](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-r) but hitting an error in section 5.2 (using covnets with small datasets) which I don't fully understand.

The model using 2,000 training samples (and 1,000 validation samples) from [Dogs vs. Cats](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/) is supposedly demonstrating the value of data augmentation and dropouts in improving accuracy when using small datasets:

```r
datagen <- image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1/255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE
)

test_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  directory = train_dir,
  generator = datagen,
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 32,
  class_mode = "binary"
)

validation_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  test_datagen,
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 32,
  class_mode = "binary"
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 100,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
```

However, after 63 steps of the first epoch, Tensorflow errors:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 10000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

I understand that this is because in a sample of 2,000 images, there's only 62.5 batches of 32; but `flow_images_from_directory()` [should result in an endless loop of augmented images](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/keras/versions/2.1.6/topics/flow_images_from_directory), so I don't understand why that's not being passed to `fit()`

> flow_images_from_directory {keras}: Yields batches indefinitely, in an infinite loop

Is there a solution to make data augmentation work? I can't find reference to using `repeat()` as suggested by the error and [this Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509425/how-to-use-repeat-function-when-building-data-in-keras?rq=1)  within the R implementation of Keras. [The same question has been asked regarding the Python version of the book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65661950/keras-data-augmentation-with-imagedatagenerator-your-input-ran-out-of-data), but the "solutions" of using smaller batches don't really solve the problem either when the generator should be outputting an infinite steam of augmented images.

Comment: If you loop over generator it will generate/yield infinite batches. For training, TensorFlow creates `tf.data.Dataset` from that generator to handle steps per epoch.

Comment: How do I loop over it in R? Calling train_generator.repeat() works in Python, but obviously not in R, and repeat(train_generator) loops to infinity before being used by fit().

Comment: the R package `tfdatasets` has many functions for interacting with `tf.data.Dataset` objects, including the function `dataset_repeat()`